# Checking relationship between two categorical object data types column in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science, feature-selection

In my Pandas DataFrame there are two categorical variable one is the **target** which **has 2 unique values**  & the other one is the **feature** which has **300 unique values** now I want to check the relationship between two variables using **ChiSquare test** now the data types of the two-column is the **object** so how can I perform the **chi-square** test or check the relationship between two columns that is - **is the two-column is Correlated or not**

Answer (score 1):

300 unique values in a variable is too much, still you can use below lines of code to test:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

table = pd.crosstab(df['Feature_Var'],df['Target_Var'])
print(table)
stat, pvalue, dof, expected = chi2_contingency(table)
print('Chi-sq Test Statistics = %.3f \nP-Value = %.3f \nDegrees of Freedom = %.3f' % (stat, pvalue, dof))
```

Comment: He's asking for a two columns correlation, not for a column levels/target correlation.

Comment: Yup I am asking two-column correlation not the correlation between the values of  two columns I want to see if two-column is related to one another or not

Comment: @geek - Can you post an example?

Comment: yup 300 unique values are too much but the dataset contains 4000 rows

Comment: Example- target columns contain only Yes and No & the other column which is feature contains the name of the devices

Comment: @manojk You may try `df = pd.DataFrame({"f":np.random.choice(["a","b","c"], 1000, True, [.2,.4,.4]), "t":np.random.randint(0,2,1000)})`

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov - Sorry if I am not able to understand, but OP mentioned that both columns are categorical, personally I know we can't directly find correlation between 2 categorical variables, I can only think of a chi-square test.

Comment: @manojk  Yes, we cannot do a correlation test on two categorical variables, even if we converted them to numbers. The reason -- the conversion will be unordered. But your approach seems to work to me after looking at it closer.... I think it's closest what can be done answering OP.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov - Thanks, this is what I understand from a pandas two categorical columns correlation, actually two categorical columns correlation is same as chi-square test for relationship between two variables.